# Spring - requests arguments list

Tags: java, spring, http-request-parameters

My url looks like this:

```
config_add?link=link1&time=time1&link=link2&time=time2
```

and I handle it using List:

```
@RequestMapping("/config_add")
    public ModelAndView configAdd(
        @RequestParam(value = "link", required = false) List<String> links,
        @RequestParam(value = "time", required = false) List<String> times)
```

It works fine but I noticed some strange behavior.

```
config_add?link=&time=&link=&time=
```

puts two empty strings each list (size =2, as expected)

```
config_add?link=link1&time=time1
```

puts link1 to links and time1 to times (size = 1, as expected)

but when i use

```
config_add?link=&time=
```

resolve to two empty lists (size = 0, I would rather expect lists with one empty string)

Am I doing something wrong? Or should I write separated logic in this case?

Comment: Why do you expect a list with one empty string?

Comment: Looking at the http payload send by the browser should point you in the right direction.